# How to deploy azure cloud service package via command line?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

I'm developing web service, which published as web role in cloud service. I need to  configure our TeamCity service for this service update deployment.

Probably I need to find out how to update service via command line.
At that moment I can generate service packages using cspack utility and update the service manually in Azure portal. Cloud service has remote access and I know username and password.

Probably I must use msbuild or msdeploy utility, but I can't find how to use them with cloud service package and remote access credentials.